# .htaccess not redirecting website to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm writing my redirect for my website but I can't get it to work, I have split it out so it will automatically redirect to https://www.whereshouldieat.ie, but since adding a rewrite for the index.php the redirect for the site doesn't work, and even in deleting the rewrite of the index.php it won't redirect to what I have it set to. See below what I have.

```
#rewrite domain name
RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.whereshouldieat.ie/$1 [R,L]

#rewrite index.php        
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

    ## Leverage browser caching at HostPapa ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## End leverage browser caching ##
```

Could someone advise? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this, (not tested !)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

hope this helps.